# Go method fails : multiple-value in a single value context

Tags: go

I have the following struct:

```
type OpList struct  {
    Name   xml.Name `xml:"Ser"`
    Servs []Ser `xml:"Ser"`
}
```

I have a method:

```
func GetInfo() (*OpList, error){  
    //If I print here the results gets printed
    fmt.Println(OpList.Servs)
    return OpList, nil
}
```

Accessing the list works absolutely fine inside of the method

But when I call this method and try to access it fails with the message: multiple-value in a single value context

```
bn:=GetInfo()
fmt.Printf(bn.Servs)
```

I am actually not getting that much information in net as well. How do I access the value returned from a typical method like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try :

```
bn, err := GetInfo()
fmt.Printf(bn.Servs)
```

Comment: works fine. Have a doubt , it says "err" has been declared but not used . So compiling purpose I have just printed it . Is there any way to avoid err?

Comment: You can use `_` instead of `err` or you can actually check for error and handle it.

Comment: If you ignore errors, you'll just be more confused later.